# Objective C - Attribute values into Variables

Tags: objective-c, xcode, attributes, xcode6

I'm new to objective-C, having a programming background mainly in C++, and believe this to be an easy question although I can't find the answer to what I'm looking for. I'm using Xcode 6 as of now.

I have an entity "Song" in which I have various attributes, "Description", "Tempo", etc. My tempo attribute, for example, is limited to integers, and I want to be able to manipulate any/all of those tempo values for each Song at a given time. Upon a dedicated button click, I want to either edit the values or put all of the values in an array (array[0] = Song 1 Tempo, array[1] = Song 2 Tempo, etc), so mainly I need to get those individual values into variables, or so I think.

I feel as though my limited knowledge of attributes and entities is preventing me from being able to connect the bridge between them and variables, the latter of which I'm used to working with in C++, of course. Any suggestions or tips would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Pat

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute will return collection type object like dictionary or array. So you can iterate your attributes values and just add in `NSMutableArray.`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I feel as if I get what you mean but am unable to get a working code. How do I point the NSMutableArray to my attribute? Do you have an example code? Thanks very much in advance.